# ActiveFence in .Net update with delay

Tags: c#, .net

I have the problem. I am sending some data to ActiveFence through API to check it and it is calling a callback that updates the column Hide if it has violations. And that all works. But what I want is to do that while creating object. For example Comment. So I create comment send content and update that, but in same endpoint it doesn't update the Hide value for that comment. Here is code snippet:

```
var comment = await _commentService.CreateComment(model, memberId);
        
await ActiveFenceAsync(comment.Id.ToString(), memberId);

var isHide = await _commentService.GetCommentHideStatusAsync(comment.Id.ToString());

return new CommentResponse(
    ...
    isHide ?? false,
    ...);
```

So **isHide** reads old value. But when I retrieve that value in another endpoint, it is updated, so the problem is it doesn't read it on time. I tried adding delays and WhenAll and similar mechanisms but nothing helped, and I think that delay is because ActiveFence in background calls endpoint for updating its value, but before that it returns response.
Any help, tip?